# Google maps is not displaying in my activity in release build mode

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to display a Google Map in my android application.

I've registered my API key, and put the provided file ("google_maps_api.xml") into both

```
src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml
src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml
```

In Manifest, I've declared:

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

This way it works flawless if I run it on my phone with Android Studio's play button (debug mode).

However, if I request Android Studio to "Generate Signed Bundle/APK", and install manually this release-variant (still onto my phone):

```
adb install my-app-release.apk
```

Then the map simply doesn't display, and I also don't have any logs from logcat (because this is a release variant with disabled debugging).

Why this is happenning and how can I resolve it?

Note: I'm not publishing this application into the Store, just I want to build the release variant and keep the maps working.

Comment: It is because of your SHA key which mush be for signed apk.

Comment: I dont understand this. Please describe a bit more. I have my own selfsigned keys for release build.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do 2 steps:

1.) manually acquire the SHA-1 fingerprint of my self-signed certificate which is used during generating the signed build:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore [your_certificate] -alias [your_alias]
```

2.) adding the SHA-1 fingerprint to Google Cloud Console

After the above two steps, Google Maps is behaving the same in release and debug builds.